# How to get links to the last N posts in a specific category?

Tags: posts, title

I want to display the titles of the last N posts in a specific category. I am using the following code:

```
        <?php
        $cat_id=get_cat_ID('category1');
            $posts = get_posts ("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=3");
            if ($posts) 
        {
        foreach ($posts as $post):
            setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <h2><?php
            //the_title(); 
            ?>
            </h2>
            <?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE ); ?>
            <?php //the_content();
            ?> 
            <?php endforeach;
        }
            ?>
```

But, instead of getting titles of the last 3 posts, I get TWO (instead of three) links, and even worse, the links returned are not post titles. They simply read "Next post in category". However, their href works well (I can open post content by clicking on them). How should I modify the code so that I get titles to last N posts with category "category1", where I can open the post content (in new page) when I click the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no parameter named `cat` in `get_posts`. Use `category` instead to input comma separated category IDs or `category_name` to directly inserting category name.

Second, in your code you have commented out the title of the post.
Try this code.

```
<?php
    $cat_id = get_cat_ID('category1');
    $posts = get_posts( "category=$cat_id&posts_per_page=3" );
    if ($posts) {
        foreach ($posts as $post): setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php endforeach;
    }
?>
```

The reason this shows two post could be because your category have 2 posts only. Make sure your category have atleast 3 posts.

You can change `posts_per_page=3` in above code to whatever number of posts you want to list. If you want to list 10 posts, change it to `posts_per_page=10` and if you want to list all posts then use `-1` like this `posts_per_page=-1`

Comment: No my category has four posts. I am sure.

Comment: I already used your code. It just lists titles in this category. I want titles shown as **links to relevant post contents**. Also putting <?php the_title();?> inside an anchor tag does not help as I don't know how to set it href.

Comment: I updated answer with suggested change. Now post title links to posts. Use updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function in your theme. Add this function to your theme's functions.php and call function. This function gives you latest posts from category.

```
function latest_from_category( $post_count, $category) {
    $cid = get_cat_ID($category);
    $last_by_cat = new WP_Query('orderby=date&cat='.$cid.'&posts_per_page='.$post_count);
    echo '<h4>Latest Post From Category</h4> <ul>';
    while ($last_by_cat->have_posts()) : $last_by_cat->the_post();
?>
    <li><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile;
echo '</ul>';
}
```

Usage of this function.

```
<?php latest_from_category('5','WordPress');?>
```

The number defines count of links and WordPress is a category name.

Answer (score 0):

@Rebert Hue your code works fine. However, before checking out your edited answer, I modified my code as follows, which also sets href correctly:

```
<?php
                $cat_id=get_cat_ID('mycategory');
                    $posts = get_posts ("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=3");
                    if ($posts) 
                {
                foreach ($posts as $post):
                    setup_postdata($post); ?>
               <h2>
                    <a href="<?php _a(get_permalink());">
                           <?php the_title()?>

                    </a>
               </h2>

                    <?php endforeach;
                }
                    ?>
```